# Unstring an equation that consist of integers and primitives

Tags: python, string, integer, primitive

Input:

```
1st integer given: 3, 
2nd integer given: 2, 
Primitives given in a STRING: '+'
```

Expected output:

```
5
```

Since 3+2=5

My approach:

```
str(3)+ '+' + str(2)  --> '3+2'
int('3+2') --> Wishfully thinking: 5
```

As expected, I will get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3+2'.

Any idea how can I approach this? I must use all the input given, meaning I must use the primitives in the string ('+')

Thanks!!

Comment: You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). `ast.literal_eval('3 + 2') == 5`

Comment: Hi @minitech, I am getting a `malformed string` when trying your approach. Any suggestion?

Comment: @sgmart: How are you using it?

Comment: Just as you has show it. Python 2.7

Comment: @sgmart: It’s a Python 3 thing.

Comment: Ok, nice to know that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
first = raw_input('1st integer given: ')
second = raw_input('2nd integer given: ')
primitives = raw_input('Primitives given in a STRING: ')

equation = first+primitives+second
answer = eval(equation)
print answer
```

**Runs as:**

```
1st integer given: 3
2nd integer given: 2
Primitives given in a STRING: +
5
```

**Or:**

```
1st integer given: 99
2nd integer given: 9
Primitives given in a STRING: /
11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval.

```
eval( str(2) + '+' + str(3) )
```

You can even use this

```
print( eval( input( "insert equation: " )))
```

Or if you want to separate the values:

```
inp = input("num1 num2 operation: ")
num1, num2, operation = inp.split()
print( eval ( str(num1) + str(operation) + str(num2) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

This function recursively calls itself breaking down its components one at a time.
It also follows standard [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

```
def evaluate(str_func):
    if "-" in str_func:
        return evaluate(str_func[:str_func.index("-")].strip()) - evaluate(str_func[str_func.index("-")+1:].strip())
    if "+" in str_func:
        return evaluate(str_func[:str_func.index("+")].strip()) + evaluate(str_func[str_func.index("+")+1:].strip())
    if "*" in str_func:
        return evaluate(str_func[:str_func.index("*")].strip()) * evaluate(str_func[str_func.index("*")+1:].strip())
    if "/" in str_func:
        return evaluate(str_func[:str_func.index("/")].strip()) / evaluate(str_func[str_func.index("/")+1:].strip())
    return float(str_func.strip())

>>> evaluate("3 + 5")
8.0
>>> evaluate("3 + 5 / 2")
5.5
>>> evaluate("1 * 2 / 3 + 4 - 5")
-0.33333333333333304
>>>
```